# How to interpret coefficients in a vector autoregressive model?

Tags: interpretation, regression-coefficients, autoregressive

Can I interpret the coefficients in a VAR model in the same way as I do in a normal OLS regression?

Comment: answer by a prof from my department (University of Leicester): "Yes you can interpret the coefficients in exactly the same way"

Comment: Probably more informative to look at the impulse response function of the VAR.

Answer (score 2):

It's often pretty hard interpret the coefficients of a VAR, specially if it includes many variables and lags. As one lag of a variable says one thing and another the opposite, there are no clear dynamics between the variables you wish to investigate, usually a VAR is accompanied with tools like the impulse response function and forecast error variance decomposition.